# Print out results from a bash script with lot of continue's

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a script that uses 2 loops. 
**1st loop** - searches for a specific file and if that file exists, other tests are performed. To avoid using a lot of CPU on a server, I have decided to use `continue` in a loop. 
**2nd loop** - prints out results based on that first loop.

Script more or less looks like this:

```
for line in `find ./ -type f`; do

# first file test
   if [[ -f /directory/test1 ]]; then
        present=1
        continue
   fi
# second file test
   if [[ -f /directory/test2 ]]; then
        present=1
        continue
   fi
done

if [[ $present = '1' ]]; then
   echo "exists" 
else
   echo "does not exist"
fi
```

So basically, when the first test (first file test or second file test) is valid, `continue` will break up the loop and start the new iteration, so it won't reach the bottom of the script.

That will cause the second test to fail and the script will print only results with files that **do not exist**.

My question is: How to print out all results (exists and does not exist).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the actual script or at least all of the relevant parts?  You mention two loops but only show one here and your issue as described would not happen in the provided example.  You are also not doing anything with `line` so your loop seems ultimately pointless.

Comment: What is the point of the `line` variable here?  It looks like you're not using the output of `find` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not write it like this:

```
if [[ -f /directory/test1 || -f /directory/test2  ]]; then
    echo exists
else
    echo 'does not exist'
fi
```

Also you should [not parse the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) for the same reasons you [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Since `$line` is not being used, you may as well remove the loop.

Comment: @Kusalananda:  I'm thinking(hoping) there is more work being done within the `if` construct that may use line as OP indicated this wasn't the entire code.

Comment: If there is, it should be converted to a loop executed by `find ... -exec sh -c`.